# boost::ptr_vector with arrays: Can I be sure that its destructor calls delete[] instead of delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

I have the following case:

```
boost::ptr_vector<float> vec;

float* array = new float[4]();
vec.push_back(array);

// Add some more elements to vec..
```

How can I ensure that if I leave this scope and vec will be destroyed the ptr_vector's destructor calls `delete[]` and not `delete` on every element of `vec`. I don't understand how it should work, because the template parameter float will be the same for `float*` and `float[4]`.

Comment: If it's available to you, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<float[]>>` will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the `CloneAllocator` template parameter of `ptr_vector` to be something other than the default, `heap_clone_allocator`. There is no way to make an instance of the actual class `boost::ptr_vector<float>` use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But another allocator like view_clone_allocator just performs no deallocation. But what can I do to have functionality like a ptr_vector that deletes its containing arrays with delete[]? Using a std::vector and iterating through its elements calling delete[] on each of it should be avoided.

Comment: @morph: I don't think Boost provides one to fit this case, so write your own Clone Allocator. Presumably the reason they don't provide one is that they don't think a `ptr_vector` containing pointers to C arrays is very useful -- it's somewhat ugly in that the ptr_vector accessors give you references only to the first element of each array. I guess you end up writing `(&my_vector[0])[1]`, maintaining a separate container with the sizes, and other such nastiness. If the arrays are all size 4, then use a `vector` or `ptr_vector` of `boost::array<float,4>`.

Answer (score -4):

For the arrays containint BUILT-IN simple type items (like float or char): i think there is no difference between delete and delete[], because delete[] assumes call many destructors - for each object of the array, but build-in primitive types doesn't assume calling destructor - there is nothing to destroy there; deallocating array of floats is just deallocating solid piece of memory without executing any code that might be placed in some kind of destructor. Murr...

Comment: Hm.. I learned to call delete on pointers created with operator new and delete[] on arrays created with operator new[].

Comment: Using `delete` on an array allocated with `new[]` (and vice versa) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are correct about "what is written in books", but i am saying about "how it works in reality".

Comment: @pavelkolodin: How it works in reality depends on how the particular free store is implemented. Maybe using the wrong form will have the same effect as the correct form; maybe it will cause a runtime exception; maybe it will corrupt the heap's data structures and cause catastrophic loss of data some time in the future, in a way that's exceedingly difficult to debug.

Comment: @pavelkolodin: It depends, I can see the array form allocating some overhead to store the number of elements. In this case, before calling `free` it would be necessary to execute a pointer arithmetic operation to get back to *before* the header so that the pointer passed to `free` is the very one that `malloc` had returned. And if you call the wrong version of `delete`, then the overhead size might well be different. And then you enter *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Matthieu M: as i imagine, there is no 2 different ways to allocate an array of built-in types. It is always solid and still memory block. So there is no 2 dirrerent ways to deallocate it... Sorry for too brave assumptions everyone, but i don't see how delete[] and delete may execyte differently on array of built-in types :)

Comment: @pavelkolodin: Consider an implementation where the array form stores the size of the allocation, and the single-object form infers it from the object size. Incorrectly calling `delete` will infer the wrong size, so large blocks of memory might be wasted; incorrectly calling `delete[]` will read an invalid size, which could make almost anything happen. That's just one example of an implementation that could go wrong if you try to rely on your guesses about undefined behaviour.

Comment: As Mike Seymour says, the issue is the size of the allocation, and whether that can be known at delete time, or whether it must be stored. delete and delete[] are different operators for a reason. The downside is more than lost memory, it is a corrupted heap.